# How can I cut videos from multiple videos and merge them in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, video, merge, cut

I have a requirement where I need to cut the video between some selected time frames from different videos and merge them to make those a single video. How can I achieve this in iPhone programmatically. Are there any API's available?

Comment: Have you ever able to this? I am also looking something similar to crop and play cropped portion of video. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt use them my self but yes there are available APIs to help you do this.

Have a look at AV Foundation programming guideline

I also recommend you to check the WWDC 2010 video session "Editing media with AV Foundation"

Cheers